# change ng-model value using filter Angular js

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters, angular-controller

Is it possible to update `ng-model` value using `filter` on input field? I have this text field:

`<input type="text" ng-model="dateOfJoining" ng-value="dateOfJoining | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'">`

in `ng-model` i have this default value:- `2016-12-31T18:30:00.000Z` and using filter i am able to display the formatted date value in `'dd-MM-yyyy'` format but my problem is when i load another view which is belongs to the same controller and come back to this text field then the filtered value got vanished and the default value is displayed. I want to update `ng-model` value using `filter` so that i will be sure that the value is filtered properly and i can send filtered value to server also.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, you just check [my code in plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yi2Y03tbYfuEGzFcy8E0?p=preview) i think it may help you

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.20" data-semver="1.2.20" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap@3.1.1" data-semver="3.1.1" src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular-ui-bootstrap@0.11.0" data-semver="0.11.0" src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);



    myApp.controller('myAppCtrl', function($scope) {

     $scope.MyDate = "2016-12-31T18:30:00.000Z";
    });

    angular.module('myApp').directive('formattedDate', function(dateFilter) {
      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
          format: "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
          ngModelController.$parsers.push(function(data) {
            //convert data from view format to model format
            return dateFilter(data, scope.format); //converted
          });

          ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
            //convert data from model format to view format
            return dateFilter(data, scope.format); //converted
          });
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myAppCtrl">


      {{MyDate | date:'medium'}}
      <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model= "MyDate" formatted-date format="medium" />
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: we have this date format `2014-09-23T15:26:49.1513672Z` what does it mean? my only challenge is to convert this format to javascripr date() object but i don't want to use `new Date('2014-09-23T15:26:49.1513672Z');` is there any other easy alternative available?

Comment: without date() you can use this $scope.MyDate = "2016-12-31T18:30:00.000Z";

Comment: Ya i have already tried it is working without `date()` but see my text field have a uib datepicker and it looks like `<input type="text" class="form-control custom-form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="expiryDate" is-open="expiryDateCal.opened" datepicker-options="expiryDateOptions" name="expiryDate" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" ng-value="expiryDate | date:format"/>` so i am not sure how can i apply your code on this text field?

Comment: are you using importLC.main.expiryDate in other location ? if not then you can change ng-model="importLC.main.expiryDate" to ng-model="MyDate"

Comment: you have changed `ng-model="importLC.main.expiryDate"` to `ng-model="expiryDate"`, then you need to change `$scope.MyDate = "2016-12-31T18:30:00.000Z";` to `$scope.expiryDate = "2016-12-31T18:30:00.000Z";`